Is the non-degeneracy axiom required in definition of field?
There are several definitions of field that don't require the non-degeneracy axiom. One such definition can be found on Wikipedia page, where the non-degeneracy is absent.
However, on that same page, there's this line:

Even more succinctly: a field is a commutative ring where 0 ≠ 1 and all nonzero elements are invertible under multiplication.

Which clearly incorporates the non-degeneracy axiom.
Also, some online resources and books, for example this one, do include the axiom into the definition of field while others don't.
So, what version is the correct one?

Why the operator theory tag? Also, like most things, there is no completely universal definition. However, mostly I see non degeneracy required for fields (for rings with unity, it is even less standard)

@Malady, the incorrect tag was mentally added since I was reading operator theory, it's been removed (someone did this for me).

You say "others don't" and give a reference". That reference has $1\ne 0$ as part of axiom (viii). I don't believe that "others don't", The Wiki page is simply mistaken/careless.

Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427078/is-0-a-field and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756806/why-isnt-the-zero-ring-the-field-with-one-element

@ancientmathematician I updated the link. There're others also.

@MartinBrandenburg, I closed the question.

The zero ring behaves very badly for the following reasons, all of which are somewhat related:

It does not have a well-defined characteristic.
It does not have a prime subfield.
It does not admit any proper field extensions.
There aren't even any nonzero polynomials over it.

So in terms of field theory, the zero ring is an extraordinarily misbehaving exception that nobody wants to deal with. So we don't.
Also, note on the Wikipedia page, one of the axioms in the long definition says that $0$ and $1$ must be distinct.


Please don't answer duplicate questions. This is against the site policy. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards
